# Getting sqlite data to scope in angular in hybrid mobile app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, callback, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi I am trying to create a mobile app using sqlite for storage. I have created a service for sqlite db and trying to get the data from database to controller scope, i tried with a callback, but doesn't work. please help.

this is the code in sqlite service

```
  self.getAll = function(table_name, cb) {

    this.db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM " + table_name, [],
            function(tx, result) {


                cb(result.rows);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("Error occurred while getting the data.");
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
}
```

this is the code in the main controller

```
 function getData(data) {
 console.log("logging from getData");
 console.log(data);

 $scope.all = data;

}

sqlite.getAll("todo", getData);


console.log('logging results outside');
console.log($scope.all);
```

results don't get assigned to the $scope.all variable, what can i do to get the results, the console log from within the getData function works and shows the table data.

Comment: I'm trying to build a standalone mobile app without using a server. want to use the sqlite storage in the phone for data saving

Comment: then sorry for the comment, I'm gonna remove it

Comment: @fodma1 If he is using sqllite it is inteded to run on the front-end. Bmax, could you possible post a plunkr

Comment: @Bmax the last console.log($scope.all) will always be undefined because it runs before data arrives. Rather display the all vairable in your html like {{ all }}

Comment: @johan thanks it worked, had to use $timeout though

Comment: Cool glad it helped, I moved the comment to an answer, if you could accept that

Answer (score 0):

The last console.log($scope.all) will always be undefined because it runs before data arrives. Rather display the all variable in your html like {{ all }}
Or use a $watch on the variable, or do your assignments inside the function after the data arrives. Depends what you want to do.